# postgresql index not used on range queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this postgresql table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    fecha_dato date NULL,
    codpers numeric NULL,
    ...
CREATE INDEX ix_fecha_dato ON new_table USING btree (fecha_dato);
CREATE INDEX ix_codpers ON new_table USING hash (codpers);
```

and a problem with range queries:

```
explain SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE codpers>=10000000 and codpers<10000003;

 QUERY PLAN                                                                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Seq Scan on tablon_base_pf_202006  (cost=0.00..5705226.14 rows=2 width=1404)|
  Filter: ((codpers >= 10000000::numeric) AND (codpers < 10000002::numeric))|
  
  
explain SELECT * FROM tablones.tablon_base_pf_202006 where codpers in (10000000,10000001, 10000002); 
 
 QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap Heap Scan on tablon_base_pf_202006  (cost=18.81..30.84 rows=3 width=1404)   
  Recheck Cond: (codpers = ANY ('{10000000,10000001,10000002}'::numeric[]))        
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_hashtablon_base_pf_202006  (cost=0.00..18.81 rows=3 w
        Index Cond: (codpers = ANY ('{10000000,10000001,10000002}'::numeric[]))
```

both queries return same 3 records, first spend more than 5 minutes and explain shows a secuential scan, index on `codpers` is not used.
Second one spend less than 1 second, use `codpers` index without problem.

Any clue why?

Answer (score 2):

change `ix_codpers` to:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_codpers ON new_table USING btree (codpers);
```

**Hash** indexes are faster than **btree** indexes but can't be used for range queries, only for direct key search.